# ast or syntax tree for all the locals() and globals() in a python file

Tags: python, global, loader, local-variables, built-in

How do I get the tree for all the `locals()` and `globals()` in a python file parsed in a string or a shell stdout. I am getting this right now for globals:

```
{ 
    '__name__': '__main__', 
    '__doc__': None, 
    '__package__': None, 
    '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter' >, 
    '__spec__': None, 
    '__annotations__': { }, 
    '__builtins__': <module 'builtins'(built -in) >
}
```

Comment: If you haven't declared any other variables in \_\_main__ then what you show here is what you'll get from *print(globals())* and *print(locals())*. So what is your problem?

Comment: `<module 'builtins'(built -in) >` is needed as a indepth dict. `<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter' >` along.